# How do I simulate the bag-of-words model in R to fit into the SVM

Tags: r, machine-learning

My question: How could I apply the bag-of-words model as features to feed into svm in R?

I've generated some data be low:

```
Title Salary
"Software Engineer" 100000
"Software Engineer" 120000
"Junior Software Engineer" 60000
"Junior Software Engineer" 70000
"Senior Software Engineer" 130000
```

Using read.table, I could get a matrix of 2*n of (character, numeric). I want to apply the "bag of words" to the Title column. However, if I just manually split any of the entries, e.g.

```
jobs['Title'][1,] <- strsplit(jobs['Title'][1,], ' ')
```

This gives:

```
Title Salary
"Software" 100000
"Software Engineer" 120000
"Junior Software Engineer" 60000
"Junior Software Engineer" 70000
"Senior Software Engineer" 130000
```

Rather than I expected:

```
Title Salary
["Software", "Engineer"] 100000
"Software Engineer" 120000
"Junior Software Engineer" 60000
"Junior Software Engineer" 70000
"Senior Software Engineer" 130000
```

My code to invoke SVM looks like this:

```
jobs <- read.table("jobs.data", header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
index <- 1:nrow(jobs)
testindex <- sample(index, trunc(length(index)/3))
testset <- jobs[testindex,]
trainset <- jobs[-testindex,]
svm.model <- svm(Salary ~ ., data = trainset, cost = 10, gamma = 1)
svm.pred <- predict(svm.model, testset)
```

I think I'm getting it wrong but I haven't found the way to do it, could someone please share how I should do it?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.  Is this really the data you're working with?  If all the titles end in "Software Engineer", then those words are useless for prediction anyway.  All you care about is the prefix -- "Junior", "Senior", or nothing.  Can you be more specific about the task you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks rmalouf. In this special case, yes, only the "junior", "principal" matters, but I will have more job titles like "hardware engineer", "iphone magician" etc... the point is not the data but I want to model the title as a bag of words, but I didn't quite understand how that would work in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is worrying that a basic question question in machine learning question was downvoted. So let me answer my own question.

1. Each word is assigned a vector, with 1 being present and 0 being absent. Essentially, this will form a sparse matrix, plus a column of the class.
2. Use Python, use the dictionaries to represent a bag of words instead. It is far easier to do string manipulation in Python. Feed the data into NLTK or PyOrange.

The gist here is that R does not seem to be a language for string manipulation. You may use the tm library to help you out.

I hope that helps anyone facing similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy to do that in R with the tm package :

```
require(Matrix)
require(e1071) 
require(tm)
options(stringsAsFactors = F)

jobs <- data.frame(Title = c("Software Engineer", "Software Engineer", 
                             "Junior Software Engineer", "Junior Software Engineer", 
                             "Senior Software Engineer", "Hardware Engineer"),
                   Salary = c(100000, 120000,
                              60000, 70000,
                              130000, 110000))

# Create the corpus
MyCorpus <- VCorpus(VectorSource(jobs$Title),  readerControl = list(language = "en"))
content(MyCorpus[[1]])

# Some preprocessing
MyCorpus <- tm_map(MyCorpus, content_transformer(tolower))
content(MyCorpus[[1]])

# Create the Document-Term matrix
DTM <- DocumentTermMatrix(MyCorpus, 
                          control = list(bounds = list(global = c(0, Inf)))) 
dim(DTM)
inspect(DTM)

# Create a sparse matrix to put into SVM
sparse_DTM <- sparseMatrix(i = DTM$i, j = DTM$j, x = DTM$v,
                               dims = dim(DTM),
                               dimnames = list(rownames(DTM), colnames(DTM)))

# SVM
svm.model <- svm(sparse_DTM, jobs$Salary, cost = 10, gamma = 1)
```

I let you deal with the train/test sets, and go further into tm package help.